# Python: How can I add a parameter to an itertools function?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to create a function which returns a function creating an iterator (like something from itertools), but with a parameter set by the outer function.

For example, say I want to take a running sum, but exclude values that are larger than a given cutoff (which is the parameter of the function).

So, say I have a list like this:

```py
x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 25, 1, 1]
```

And I want a function that would take the running sum, but ignore values greater than 10, to give me an output like this:

```py
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
```

This code will do the trick:

```py
t = 10
accumulate(x,lambda x,y:x if y>=t else x+y)
```

But now I want to make a function which returns a function like the above, where I can pass it the value t as the parameter.
This is what I tried:

```py
def sum_small_nums(t):
    def F(x):
        new_x = accumulate(x,lambda x,y: x if y>=t else x+y)
    return F
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. I can create a function from the above, but when I try to call it, I don't get the output I am expecting (e.g. I get 'None' instead of a list):

```py
sum_under_10 = sum_small_nums(10)
print(sum_under_10)
x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 25, 1, 1]
x2 = sum_under_10(x)
print(x2)
```

returns

```
<function sum_small_nums.<locals>.F at 0x7feab135a1f0>
None
```

Comment: Do you intend that if the first element is over 25, the accumulator starts at that value instead of zero?

Comment: @kaya3 good point, though it's not so relevant to me in this case, as this was a simplified example. The 'initial' argument of accumulate should solve that if necessary I think. The answer below solved my real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close! Need to `return` the list from the inner function:

```py
def sum_small_nums(t):
    def F(x):
        new_x = accumulate(x, lambda x, y: x if y >= t else x + y)
        return list(new_x)
   return F
```

When you don't `return` anything from a function, `None` is implicitly returned.